# request post vs axios post resolve different result

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I used request and wrap it with a promise, but I want to write cleaner code using axios, somehow I got internal serval error (Request failed with status code 401), I don't have access to backend code I have no clue what is going on.

```
//worked
response = yield new Promise(resolve => {
  resolve(request.post(api, {form: {id: 1, user: 1}}))
})

//doesn't work
response = yield axios.post(api, {id: 1, user: 1})
```

Comment: Check request's headers if they are the same for both requests. Take a look if request (module) has a custom configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, you are sending an application/x-www-form-urlencoded  request!  Turns out it's not so easy with axios.  Here in the readme:

https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

There are a number of  techniques described there. Here is one that works on the server side in node:

```
var querystring = require('querystring')
axios.post('/foo', querystring.stringify({id: user: 1})
```

Looks like in this case, request gives you the cleaner looking code!